# why custom dateformats not working in oracle bi web service parameter?

Tags: web-services, soapui, bi-publisher

I am using **Soap-UI** to call **Oracle-BI** web service `runReport` to generate a report. Its working fine for reports with no report parameters. But when I am passing `Date` parameters with `dateFormatString` defined, the report doesn't show any result. Basically, as per my understanding, the web service can't parse the date correctly. Here's what I tried -

```
<v2:parameterNameValues>
   <v2:listOfParamNameValues>
      <!--Other parameters-->
      <v2:item>            
         <v2:dataType>Date</v2:dataType>
         <v2:dateFormatString>dd-MM-yyyy</v2:dateFormatString>
         <v2:name>val_from_dt_in</v2:name>
         <v2:values>                        
            <v2:item>01-01-2013</v2:item>
         </v2:values>
      </v2:item>
   <v2:listOfParamNameValues>
<v2:parameterNameValues>
```

According to oracle docs, the `dateFormatString` parameter will take any `Java` date time format string. I have tried `dd-MMM-yyyy` and `yyyy-MM-dd` also. But it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: soapUI has an option in the setting which when set generates type information and example values. Try this option to see what date format is acceptable. the option is available under settings>WSDL Settings and the options are (1)Generate example values in new requests, (2) Generate comments with type information in new requests.

Answer (score 0):

try this format please:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```